# Argument not taken into account when using C++ dll in excel

Tags: c++, excel, dll

Hello I am trying to create a simple C++ dll to be used in Excel.

Here is what I did:

.cpp file:

```
    double _stdcall Test(double z)
{
    return z+2.0;
}
```

.def file:

```
LIBRARY
EXPORTS
Test
```

In visual studio:
Project Properties > Configuration properties > Command > "Path/EXCEL.EXE"

Configuration manager > Platform > x64

In VBA:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function Test Lib _
"Path\MyDLL" (ByVal z As Double) As Double
```

But when I call Test(2) in Excel, it returns 2, and not 4. It seems like argument are seen as 0 alway (actually if I output the value of z in a file while calling the function, it is 2.122e-314).

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit 1:
If I change the argument and return value to int and in VBA to Long, Test(2) returns 3.

Anyone has an idea why the argument is 1 for int?

Comment: Everything works for me. Did you remember to set the Module Definition File to your .def file? What is this `Project Properties > Configuration properties > Command > "Path/EXCEL.EXE"`. I do not have such an option.

Comment: If I do not put this, I get the following error:

"path/MyDLL.dll" is not a valid Win32 application.

The thing is that the def file probably works fine, since the function gets called, it's just that the Excel argument does not get taken into account

Comment: Your C++ compiler does not know that the function is getting exported.  So it expects the argument to be passed differently, floating point is done with SSE instructions and the argument is passed through the XMM0 register.  Excel however assumes that the argument should be passed the traditional way, in FPU register ST0.  Put `__declspec(dllexport)` in front of the function to fix the problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input, however it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies: Would have posted this as a comment but can't yet:

First: Your function may be exported as a C++ mangled name. 
Use extern "C" to prevent name mangling. There are other ways to do this, but this is most direct. However if the Test function is successfully being called I'm not sure this is the issue.

Using extern "C" your C function would look like this.

```
extern "C"
double _stdcall Test(double z)
{
    return z+2.0;
}
```

Second: Are you absolutely certain you are picking up the right DLL, not an old one which is missing your fixes? Try changing the function name to something more specific in your source and in the Excel VBA wrapper.

Third: If you are not running on a 64bit Excel system remove the PtrSafe declaration from your function specification in VB and recompile as 32-bit.

Fourth: Do not try to call your DLL directly from an Excel Cell. Wrap the function in VBA (example below) or use the CALL function.

The code below is an example how to wrap write a VBA cell function.

```
Public Function CellFunction_Test(x As Double) As Double
'' Tells excel to call this function only if the inputs change
'' and not on every recalculation
Application.Volatile False

'' Set an error handler, good practise for more complicated functions you might write later
On Error GoTo CellFunction_Test_EH:

'' Call into the DLL
CellFunction_Test = Test(x)
Exit Function

'' Error Handler
CellFunction_Test_EH:
CellFunction_Test = "Error - " & Err.Description
End Function
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for adding your input, really appreciate it.

1. I added the extern "C" line. Did not change anything.
2. Tried again using a new project, so I am certain yes, but still no luck.
3. I am running a x64 Excel 2013 edition...

I can debug the program in Excel, and the function indeed gets called. However it is like if the stack is cleaned between the Excel call and the C++ execution. Because the value of z is 2e-314 if passed by value, and unable to read memory exception if I pass it by reference and give the adress in the C++ function argument list.

Maybe that clarifies

Comment: Are you calling this function from an Excel cell directly (e.g =TEST(2)  ) or from VBA as a function call with in a Macro or other function?

Comment: Thank you guys, fourth point solved it for me! Thank you so much, however I don't know exactly why...